# For FIPS Enabled machine RSA key is not working

Tags: linux, redhat, fips

For RHEL 8.0 I had FIPS mode enabled machine,however RSA key does not work.
If i am creating RSA key in FIPS disabled mode then it works, were as the same RSA key does not work if FIPS enable mode.

Whether RSA key works in FIPS enabled mode for os RHEL 8.0 onward.

Comment: Is your RSA key 2048-bit or longer?

Comment: Please provide more details (steps took, commands, their outputs, ...). [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).